# Use Where Clause With Merge

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, merge

In the below syntax with the `When Matched` is it possible to only update if the value in the update table differs from the value in the employee table?  Something similar to my below DDL - but of course this throws an error and does not work.

What should I update in my syntax to only update rows that are different?  My desired update would be to not iterate each and every row that matches, but only update `emp44 & emp55` since the address is different.

The error presented is

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

**Syntax**

```
  DECLARE @Emp Table (empid varchar(10), empaddress varchar(100))
  Insert Into @Emp Values 
  ('emp11', '111 No Blue'), 
  ('emp22', '222 No Blue'),
  ('emp33', '333 No Blue'), 
  ('emp44', '444 No Blue'),
  ('emp55', '555 No Blue');

Declare @EmpUpdates TABLE (empid varchar(10), empaddress varchar(100))
Insert Into @EmpUpdates Values
('emp11', '111 No Blue'), 
('emp22', '222 No Blue'),
('emp33', '333 No Blue'), 
('emp44', '999 No Blue'),
('emp55', '888 No Blue'),
('emp66', '4141 No Blue');

MERGE @Emp emp
Using @EmpUpdates eup
ON emp.empid = eup.empid
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET emp.empaddress = eup.empaddress
WHERE emp.empaddress <> eup.empaddress
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (empid, empaddress)
VALUES(eup.empid, eup.empaddress)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is no `WHERE` in that part of the `MERGE` statement. See [`MERGE (Transact-SQL)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) in the documentation for syntax help.

There is an optional `AND` part in `WHEN MATCHED` clause so the straightforward answer is to move the condition there:

```
MERGE @Emp emp
USING @EmpUpdates eup
ON emp.empid = eup.empid
WHEN MATCHED 
     AND emp.empaddress <> eup.empaddress
  THEN
    UPDATE
    SET emp.empaddress = eup.empaddress
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
  THEN 
    INSERT (empid, empaddress)
    VALUES (eup.empid, eup.empaddress) ;
```

Be careful to handle nulls correctly there (if `empaddress` is nullable).

It is sometimes more explicit (and efficient) to perform the operations in two separate statements (`UPDATE` and `INSERT` in your case) in a transaction.

Also, be aware there have been (and still are) [some issues with `MERGE`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).